# Project does not build after changing encoding

Tags: c++, visual-studio, encoding

So, I was working with my project, when suddenly visual studio warned me that my line endings were not consistent. It then asked if I would like to re-encode the files on the project. I clicked on yes and selected the "unicode" option.

After that I cannot build my project anymore, and the error that it gives are really abstract.

It basically says that there are 3 unresolved symbols, with  the code `LNK2019`.

I am really lost because I didn't change anything on the code that would make it crash. I also went really fast through the message, so I couldn't read much about it.

On the project properties the character set is `Use Unicode Character Set`.
Also the language extension option is not disabled.

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall lh::Heightmap::Heightmap(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,int,int,int)" (??0Heightmap@lh@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@HHH@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Teste::Teste(int,int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,float)" (??0Teste@@QAE@HHV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@M@Z) C:\Users\Leonardo\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\lhengine\lhengine\teste.obj lhengine
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall lh::Heightmap::~Heightmap(void)" (??1Heightmap@lh@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function __unwindfunclet$??0Teste@@QAE@HHV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@M@Z$7 C:\Users\Leonardo\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\lhengine\lhengine\teste.obj lhengine
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall lh::Heightmap::draw(void)" (?draw@Heightmap@lh@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall Teste::render(void)" (?render@Teste@@EAEXXZ)    C:\Users\Leonardo\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\lhengine\lhengine\teste.obj lhengine
Error   4   error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Leonardo\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\lhengine\Debug\lhengine.exe lhengine
```

From what I understand it is complaining about std::string and something with char, but I have no idea what to do. I saved the files and now it is showing me this warning as well:

```
warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline  c:\users\leonardo\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\lhengine\lhengine\heightmap.cpp 1   1   lhengine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to discover the error. Basically visual studio saved the file with UTF8 encoding but with Line endings as `Unicode Line Separator (LS)`.

For some reason VS does not recognize this line ending. To make it work again I re saved the file. `Save File as... >> Save with encoding...` with line ending `Windows (CR LF)`.